# How to fix height of TR?

Tags: html, html-table, row

Is it possible to fix the height of a row (tr) on a table?

The problem appears when I shrink the window of the browser, some rows start playing around, and I can not fix the height of the row.

I tried several ways:
 `tr width="20"  / tr style="height:20px" / td height="20" / td style="height:20px"`

I am using IE7

Style

```
.tableContainer{
    color:#0076BF;
    margin: -10px 0px -10px 0px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    empty-cells:show;
    width:90%;
    text-align:left;
} 

.tableContainer tr td{
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:left;
}
```

HTML code.

```
<table class="tableContainer" cellspacing="10px">
    <tr style="height:15px;">
        <td>NHS Number</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>Date of Visit</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td colspan="3">Care Time Started</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;">&#9745;</td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;vertical-align:bottom;">Tick when<br/>                        care starts</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="90" class="tableContainerRow2">&#160;</td>
        <td >&#160;</td>
        <td width="80" class="tableContainerRow2">&#160;</td>
        <td >&#160;</td>
        <td width="40" class="tableContainerRow2">&#160;</td>
        <td  width="5">:</td>
        <td width="40" class="tableContainerRow2">&#160;</td>        
        <td >&#160;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Tables are iffy (at least, in IE) when it comes to fixing heights and not wrapping text.  I think you'll find that the only solution is to put the text inside a `div` element, like so:

```css
td.container > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
td.container {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="container">
            <div>This is a long line of text designed not to wrap 
                 when the container becomes too small.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This way, the `div`'s height is that of the containing cell and the text cannot grow the `div`, keeping the cell/row the same height no matter what the window size is.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, It seems to work, but it looks a bit messy though.

Comment: Happy to help :-) Unfortunately, messy code is usually the case in hacks and workarounds.

Comment: I use [code].container { width: 100%; max-height: 40px; overflow:hidden; }[/code] and [code]<div class='container'></div>[/code].

Comment: I've did the same method, putting a div inside a <th> tag and it worked well. I had this issue only on Chrome. FFox, Safari and IE supported well the height set on the table header. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: doesn't work in safari... you need to set the actual height and width on the div as well, not only the td

Comment: This worked for me. I applied a height to just one of my <td>'s and the rest of the row expanded uniformly. Thanks for the help Andy.

Answer (score 18):

Try putting the height into one of the cells, like this:

```
<table class="tableContainer" cellspacing="10px">
 <tr>
  <td style="height:15px;">NHS Number</td>
  <td>&#160;</td>
```

Note however, that you won't be able to make the cell smaller than the content requires it to be. In that case you would have to make the text smaller first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't use "px" in html attributes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use in style attribute.

Answer (score 11):

## Setting the `td` height to less than the *natural* height of its content

Since table cells want to be at least big enough to encase their content, if the content has no apparent height, the cells can be arbitrarily resized.

By resizing the cells, we can control the row height.

One way to do this, is to set the content with an `absolute` position within the `relative` cell, and set the `height` of the cell, and the `left` and `top` of the content.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.set-height td {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3em;
}
.set-height p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
/* table layout fixed */
.layout-fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
/* td width */
.td-width td:first-child {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
  <tr class="set-height">
    <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
    <td>Foo</td></tr><tr><td>Bar</td><td>Baz</td></tr><tr><td>Qux</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<h3>With <code>table-layout: fixed</code> applied:</h3>
<table class="layout-fixed"><tbody>
  <tr class="set-height">
    <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
    <td>Foo</td></tr><tr><td>Bar</td><td>Baz</td></tr><tr><td>Qux</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<h3>With <code>&lt;td&gt; width</code> applied:</h3>
<table class="td-width"><tbody>
  <tr class="set-height">
    <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
    <td>Foo</td></tr><tr><td>Bar</td><td>Baz</td></tr><tr><td>Qux</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**The [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) property**

The second table in the snippet above has `table-layout: fixed` applied, which causes cells to be given equal width, regardless of their content, within the parent.

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=table-layout), there are no significant compatibility issues regarding the use of `table-layout` as of Sept 12, 2019.

**Or simply apply `width` to specific cells** as in the third table.

These methods allow the cell containing the effectively sizeless content created by applying `position: absolute` to be given some arbitrary girth.

## Much more simply...

I really should have thought of this from the start; we can manipulate [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) table cell content in all the usual ways, and without completely destroying the content's natural size with `position: absolute`, we can leave the table to figure out what the width should be.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
table p {
  margin: 0;
}
.cap-height p {
  max-height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
  <tr class="cap-height">
    <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cap-height">
    <td><p>Bar</p></td>
    <td>Baz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Qux</td>
    <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Finally an answer that looks promising! Gotta try it as soon as I will be at work, I will give feedback if I don't forget.

Comment: Worked like a charm! (Warning that it does remove `text-align: center` and other centering tricks though… as it relies on `position: absolute`)

Comment: This works for the height in my case, but when using `postion: absolute`, I lose the automatic cell width.  Trying to find a way to have the table still properly calculate cell width while taking control over row height.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ash - I'm not immediately thinking of any way to keep the fully automatic width after effectively destroying the content's size, but we can force the table cells to be arbitrarily wide. I have expanded the example snippet to show one method that might help you out. I will give it some more thought, and add more details if anything useful comes to mind :)

Comment: Thanks Fred.  Note that I could have headers (<th>) to give a fixed size to the columns, but then I am concerned the headers might be too narrow or too wide.

Comment: @ash - I've added another method that seems much more useful for practical applications, and as I state, I really should have thought of it earlier.

Comment: Works for text wrap, but the rows still seems to be min-limited by font size..

Comment: @MaileCupo I'm sorry; I don't know what you mean or how I might be able to help.

Answer (score 8):

Putting div inside a td made it work for me.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr><td><div style="font-size:2px; height:2px; vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table width is 90% which is relative to it's container.

If you squeeze the page, you are probably squeezing the table width as well. The width of the cells reduce too and the browser compensate by increasing the height.

To have the height untouched, you have to make sure the widths of the cells can hold the intented content. Fixing the table width is probably something you want to try. Or perhaps play around with the min-width of the table.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this to get the result that I wanted:

```
<td style="font-size:3px; float:left; height:5px; vertical-align:middle;" colspan="7"><div style="font-size:3px; height:5px; vertical-align:middle;"><b><hr></b></div></td>
```

It refused to work with only the cell or the div and needed both.

Answer (score -6):

That is because the words are wrapping and are going on new lines hence stretching the TR. This should fix your problem:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Put that in the TR styles
Although it should work, why not just let it stretch o0

PS. i aint tested it so dont hate XD

Comment: Not hating, but there is a list of styles supported by the TD element in IE at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535911(VS.85).aspx. `overflow` isn't one of them.