# Position relative is not working on thead

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have tried to add background on header (`thead`) with the help of **pseudo element** (`:after`) because i need to display background to one edge to another edge (including both left and right side padding) but thead is not taking position relative and `thead` background which is coming from pseudo element (`:after`) is relative to the `body`, because of this background showing on whole `body`.

Here is my code

```css
.table-wrapper {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead {
  position: relative;
}

thead:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Indicator</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created On</th>
        <th>Last Login</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$200</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Expected:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just set background-color of thead ?

Comment: Because i need to set background outside of the thead (including both left and right side padding) , you can refer expected screen shot

Answer (score 2):

You can simply apply the background to all `th` elements. If your concern is to have the background cover also the *padding* created by your `table-wrapper` element, a pseude-element solution wouldn't work, since `thead` is *inside*  of that wrapper element - the padding wouldn't be covered. In this case you need to add the left and right padding to the first/last cells of each row as done here:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Indicator</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Created On</th>
      <th>Last Login</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>January</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...But my main concern is set background outside of the thead (including both left and right side padding). And why thead is not taking position relative, you can refer expected screen shot

Comment: Thanks @Johannes, I checked you answer...You added the padding both side which is not solved my problem..I updated the expected screen shot for the better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you have used `height:100%;` in the `:after` pseudoelement.

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css), using a percent height on a html element requieres his parent to have a fixed height and your thead has none.

Unfortunately you can't set a working height on a table row as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398172/setting-table-row-height/6398216), so I don't think you'll be able to acomplish what you want just with CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro. I used height: 100% in :after, because i gave position relative to his parent thead..but thead is not picking the position relative.This is the main issue