# How to control tr height of table in CSS

Tags: css, tablerow, css-tables

I try to reduce the white space between each `tr` in a table.

I have set `"table id='recTable' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\""`, that means there is no space between each `tr`(comfirmed). So what only I need to do is reduce the height of `tr` itself.

I used `"height:40px;"` for doing this, but it doest work, no change.

It always shows a `70px height`. But if I set a big height like `"height:100px;"`, which the height is more than 70px, then it will change to the height I set.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092696/how-to-fix-height-of-tr

Comment: Please search before positing!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set this explicitly in your css. For example:

```
table#recTable{width:100%; border:1px solid red;}
#recTable tr td {height:40px; border:1px solid red;}
```

HTML

```
<table id="recTable">
    <tr><td>Something</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Something else</td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qXpLM/

*Borders just for example*

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the height or line-height of your TD's or TH's within your TR.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to have a div element inside td element and fix the height of div element. It worked for me.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="max-height:92px;">
         <span style="color: #992222; font-size:36pt;font-family:Arial Baltic;">
         "     </span>
       </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted? The solution of putting a div inside the cells worked for many. Just styling the height, as proposed above, does not keep the content from expanding a td (see Jason Gennaro's fiddle).

Answer (score -1):

You can make the height smaller by changing the display. by default it is `display : table` , Change it to `display : block` for example and it should work

Comment: using display: block will remove the table view nature of tr