# Hiding text in a table cell

Tags: html

Like the title says, I have a table with many rows and columns. The text within the cells will be populated dynamically. If a column has a set width and the amount of characters exceeds this width, I want the excess text to be hidden rather than the column made wider. How can i achieve this? i tried `overflow:hidden` in the `<td>` style without success.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put div inside td - div can handle overflow: hidden

Or make table layout fixed using table style - this will cause table will not change columns width automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092696/how-to-fix-height-of-tr/2092913#2092913 tested and seems to satisfy the question and corroborate the answer.  :)