# How to set the max-height for a tr or td which is supported atleat IN CHROME

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How to set the max-height for a tr or td which is supported atleat IN CHROME?

here there is an answer which does not work for chrome:
[How to fix height of TR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092696/how-to-fix-height-of-)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, so I put it here if anyone interested:

```
<td><div style='overflow-y:scroll;max-height:70px;'>...</div></td>
```

But now I have another question; I put this div for a TD which I'm pretty sure it is huge; and I dont put this div for other TDs although I coould do for other TDs.Now my question is how I can understand the largest height for other TDs, so I can set the max-height for this TD as large as the other TDs?

Thanks