# Fixing table row height by using div in td

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I have a table. Some td's are empty, and some look like this:

```
<td><div class='divintd'>+</div></td>
```

Rows with non-empty td's get their height and width adjusted. I found from StackOverflow archive that placing td's in divs is about the only option. I implemented the code suggested here: [How to fix height of TR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092696/how-to-fix-height-of-tr) , 
but my table is still screwed up. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? CSS:

```
table td {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
}

.divintd {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Change

```
<td><div class='divintd'>+</div></td>
```

into

```
<div class='divintd'><td>+</td></div> 

.divintd td {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You can't have td wrapped by div. This is invalid markup !