# How to determine fitting table row count

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html-table

In my angularjs application, I'm displaying a "main table" on (nearly) every page. This table has thousands of logical rows, but only a few physical rows (so it's fast avoiding huge DOM overhead).

The number of physical rows is data-independent (I display them even when there are no logical rows). I implemented scrolling of the table and I want it to exactly fit in the window, so that no scrolling of the page is necessary.

For this, I need is to know how many rows do fit. The height of every row is fixed (using `height: 20px !IMPORTANT` and `overflow: hidden`). The table is the last thing on the page. So in theory, all I need is

```
var t = $("main-table");
var extraHeight = $(window).height - t.position().top - t.height() - someReserve;
var extraRows = Math.floor(extraHeight) / normalRowHeight);
physicalRows.length += extraRows;
```

The problem is that I don't know when the values settle down. I start with `physicalRows.length = 10` and after executing the above code, I should get the length right. But I don't... so I iterate it using `$timeout` and it works.

But it doesn't look good with the table growing and shrinking randomly. For example, I get the following lengths:

```
10 -> 33 -> 31 -> 30 -> 30 (done)
```

Tuning the number didn't help, even doubling `normalRowHeight` didn't avoid overshooting. I tried to limit the growth, so that shrinking is avoided. Shrinking looks especially bad as a window scrollbar gets temporarily displayed, making the right table edge jump left and back. But the only thing working was

extraRows = Math.max(extraRows, 1);

which looked terrible with the table growing row by row. Without it, I occasionally get a sequence like

```
10 -> 33 -> 56 -> 36 -> 31 -> 30 -> 30 (done)
```

The increase to 56 came from the HTML not being updated between iterations.

What can I do? Is there a way to find out when the sizes are right?

### Solution summary

I introduced the iterative computation as the direct one didn't work right. The problems had multiple causes:

- The row height was not exactly constant, which led to multiple iterations needed.
- I was listening to both window size and table position and size. There was some debouncing, but it worked for each event source separately. Sometime two events departed in the same digest iteration (i.e., before the table could resize), which led to the sequence `10 -> 33 -> 56`.

My problem was trying a too complicated solution for a simple problem.  The iterating hid the original problem and caused others. The answers made me to give up the stupid idea.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but it sounds like a simple math question. Did you check your math there? Maybe you'r missing something? Does your rows have really have a fixed-height? (max-height doesn't give fixed height, it just give the maximum height, but it can also be lower). Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @Dekel I've checked my math many times... and tried many different values. I've also added a plain `height` attribute. But even if my math was off by many pixels, it can't explain two things: **1.** the sequence `10 -> 33 -> 56`. **2.** The overshooting occurs randomly even when I grossly overestimate the height. +++ Providing an example is hard and solving the problem without it, too. I'm hoping for someone having already solved a similar problem and telling me something like "encapsulate the position reading in function XXX".

Comment: Can we see a [mcve] and/or the site? (normally I avoid looking at an unknown site) I have a feeling that no amount of written descriptions is really going to be fully understandable or testable of course

Comment: Does your Table have a fixed height? HTML Table row heights will typically change proportionally to the main table height if the table height is larger than the height of your rows. Since the table is forcing the height of your rows, you can remove the table height to resolve the issue

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry, I can't create the example now (too laborious) nor can I give you a link at the moment. I know, my description is neither very clear nor helpful. I'll create an SSCCE when I get the time for it.

Comment: @Suing No, there's no with specified for the table. And the resizing *eventually* works, it's just that it takes more than one iteration.

Comment: @maaartinus, can you put the code of your loop? You said that the sequence is `10 -> 33 -> 31 -> 30 -> 30 (done)`, but your code is only for one loop. Please provide the complete loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly :

1. you build your `main-table` from a base array of `physicalRows`
2. you  compute "how much space is left"
3. you update `physicalRows`
4. you update `main-table` based on the new array (am I correct ?)
5. back to 2

---

If this is indeed the process, you can avoid the looping part, by not using `table.height` in your formula :

```
// no extraHeight : get the full height available for your table
var height = $(window).height - t.position().top - someReserve;
// no extraRows : get the full rowCount
var rowCount = Math.floor(extraHeight) / normalRowHeight);

// if you want to display at least 10 rows :
rowCount = Math.max(rowCount, 10);

// no adding to existing size : set the correct size
physicalRows.length = rowCount;
```

Since this computation does not depend on the table height, you know for sure the value will not change when you update the rows of your table.

---

The second thing is the height of a row : the height attribute does not take into account border width or padding, so the actual height of a row in your table will be higher than just your cell's height attribute.

See for example : https://jsfiddle.net/1sm3oct1/
even with a `height: 20px !important` attribute on the table's cells, the actual height looks more like `23px`.

Play around with the css and click "Run" to see the actual's table height.

You can try to find through testing the actual size for your rows :

```
 // testing several pages show that the table's rows are 5px larger than 
 // height in css :
 var normalRowHeight = 20 + 5;
```

or use the existing table to figure out the height for one of its row :

```
 var normalRowHeight = t.height() / physicalRows.length;
```

You can also look at he following SO question : [How to fix height of TR ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092696/how-to-fix-height-of-tr)

Comment: Both detailed answers suggest similar things, so I'm awarding the bounty to the older and accepting the slightly more detailed one. I'll add some details to my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you not find any solution then you can **initially hide your dataTable** div and then when no of rows and height decide, apply no of rows and **again show dataTable**

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of adding/subtracting from the length of the physical rows, you should just try to figure it out on each resize/scroll from scratch.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).directive('calculateFit', function($window, $rootScope){
        return {
          link: function($scope, $element, $attr){
            var height = parseInt($attr.calculateFitHeight, 10);
            $window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
              $scope.$apply(calculateFit);
            }, true);
            $window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
              $scope.$apply(calculateFit);
            }, true);

            function calculateFit(){
              // This will need to be adjusted to your particular visual use case
              var availableHeight = $(window).height() - $element.position().top;
              $scope[$attr.calculateFit] = Math.ceil(availableHeight / height);
            }
            calculateFit();
          }
        }
      }).run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.rows = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
          $rootScope.rows.push(i);
        }
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .spacer {
        height: 100px;
      }
      .main-table {

      }
      .row {
        height: 20px;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div class="spacer">{{numRows}}</div>
    <div class="main-table" calculate-fit="numRows" calculate-fit-height="20">
      <div ng-repeat="row in rows | limitTo : numRows" class="row">
        {{ $index }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

You'll probably also want to debounce the resize and scroll events so that the resize/scroll performance is not affected. That might result in some visual delays, but I think its a worthwhile price to pay for smoother scrolling.

Comment: Both detailed answers suggest similar things, so I'm awarding the bounty to the older and accepting the slightly more detailed one. I'll add some details to my question.